# Power Automate Flow Version Control

Tags: version-control, power-automate

I am using Power Automate and have several flows built up. I'm curious to find out if there is a version control available for Power Automate flows.

We have multiple user having edit access to these flows and having a back up of the previous versions that can be easily restored would help.

Comment: I don’t believe it does but LogicApps has versioning.

Comment: Your best bet without actual version control is to make a copy of the flow.  I do this any time I update a flow.

Answer (score 1):

We have been developing on Power Automate for a year. Azure DevOps has been very useful for CI/CD and Git integration for Power Automate. It is possible to export the flows via solutions to Azure DevOps. You may also want to use a Git repo.

Cheers!